# Determine average value

Tags: java, math

I have to calculate an average value of my simulation. The simulation is ongoing and I want (for each iteration) to print the current average value. How do I do that?

I tried the code below (in the loop), but I do not think that the right value is calculated...

```
int average = 0;
int newValue; // Continuously updated value.

if(average == 0) {
    average = newValue;
}

average = (average + newValue)/2;
```

I also taught about store each newValue in an array and for each iteration summarize the whole array and do the calculation. However, I don't think that's a good solution, because the loop is an infinity loop so I can't really determine the size of the array.

There is also a possibility that I am thinking too much and that the code above is actually correct, but I don't think so...

Comment: You're right in thinking the code is wrong. A simple example [0,0,1] *should* give an average of 1/3, where your code would give 1/2.

Comment: This is mathematically wrong.

Comment: I don't see either loop or recursion in your code, so what's the loop you actually have, and how have you tried to do it recursively? Or do you actually try to have it done using a loop and not recursively? what is exactly updating your "continuously updated value"?

Comment: @eis Sorry for the bad title, I am trying to do it within a loop, not recursively (but if that would be a better solution, I might try it...). Edited the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would keep a running total and a count of iterations, sadly not recursive.

```
long total = 0;
int count = 0;

while ((int newValue = getValue()) > -1) // or other escape condition
{
   total += newValue;
   long average = total / ++count;
   System.out.println(average);
}
```

Comment: OP, note that you don't need the while() loop if you already are putting this in a loop. The point is that you need to accumulate your value on each loop iteration and have a control variable to divide it by.

Comment: To note, not to criticize: your `average` would never exist past the while loop, so average value would be gone by the time loop's done. That may be desired but in that case a user probably wants to do something with it in the loop, like print it (which was actually requested by OP). So that's left to the user.

Comment: Thanks! Simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
double newValue, average;
int i = 1;

while(some_stop_condition)
{
    newValue = getValue();

    average = (average*(i-1) + newValue)/i;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since some of the posters here seem to be mathematically challenged, let me state the obvious:

It's possible to get a relation between Average(n) and Average(n+1):

```
Average(n+1) = (Average(n)*n + new_value)/(n+1)
```

assuming that average is calculated with enough precision.

So it should be possible to create a recursion, though for OP purposes it simply not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet:

```
double RecursiveAvg(double A[], int i, int n)  
{  
    //Base case  
    if (i == n-1) return A[i]/n;  

    return A[i]/n + RecursiveAvg(A, i + 1, n);  
}
```

Comment: double A, int i, int n... do you expect the OP to actually understand what is happening and what should go where?

Comment: refer java guidelines, use some meaningful names. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, just keep adding each `newValue` onto a variable which just keeps incrementing by each `newValue` for each iteration and keep a record of how many times this happens with a 'counting' variable. Then to get the average for that iteration, just divide the total by the number of values taken into account.

```
int total = 0;
int count = 0;

// Whatever your loop is...
for(;;) {

    // Add the new value onto the total
    total += newValue;
    // Record the number of values added
    count ++;

    // Calculate the average for this iteration
    int average = total / count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to do this the easy way, don't actually compute your average until you need to display it or use it.  Just keep the `sum`, and the `count`, and wherever you need an average just do

```
System.out.println("Average: " + (sum/count));
```

if you want to prevent division by zero, you can use the [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a)

```
System.out.println("Average: " + (count == 0 ? 0 : sum/count));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to keep track of the total, or multiply the average by the number of iterations. You can instead weight the new value and add it directly to the average. Something like:

```
int count = 0;
double average;

while (/*whatever*/)
{
    double weighted = (newValue - average) / ++count;
    average += weighted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it the oop way:

```
class Average {
  private int count;
  private int total;

  public void add ( int value ) {
    this.total += value;
    this.count += 1;
  }

  public int get () {
    return total / count;
  }
}
```